# Not getting desired styling with response message? (Node js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

This is my mail.js file which includes this code:

```
    const sendMail = (mail) => {
    
        fetch("/contact",{
            method: "post",
            body: mail,
        }).then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        });
    };
```

This is my sendMail function in the index.js file which is sending contact form data to the desired email id:

```
    transporter.sendMail(mail, (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                  console.log(err);
                  res.status(500).send("Something went wrong.");
                } else {
                  res.status(200).send("Email successfully sent to recipient!");
                }
            });
```

And this is the HTML code of my contact form:

```
                        <div class="form">
                            <form id="contact-form" action="contact" method="post" role="form" class="php-email-form" enctype = "multipart/form-data">

                            <div class="my-3">
                                <div class="loading">Loading</div>
                                <div class="error-message"></div>
                                <div class="sent-message">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-center"><button type="submit" value="submit" title="Send Message">Send Message</button></div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

Whenever I try to submit contact from data it sends it successfully and displays the message "Email successfully sent to recipient!" But with class="error-message" styling how can I fix that?

Comment: You're missing some code samples that would affect your HTML, it's impossible to see why it would do that without your code samples

Comment: whenever I submit the message it automatically adds the ".d-block" class to the ".error-message" 
@maxshuty

Comment: Where is ".d-block" defined? Can you show that file? What is setting ".d-block" on the class ".error-message" Can you show that code?